c++ manual concatenation of c-strings function that is called twice and adds a space
I have an assignment to write a function that takes two C-string parameters and appends the second to the first just like the strcat function but without using said function. Then, write a main driver that prompts the user for two strings, calls the myStrcat function to concatenate a blank space to the end of the first string, then calls myStrcat again to concatenate the second string to the end of the first string. I can use strlen function but that's the only one from  library. I have the below written out and it obviously only calls the function once and does not add a space. I cannot for the life of me understand how to force a space into this... thanks in advance, I've literally been working on this for daaaaaays...
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void myStrcat(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main(){
    
    char s1[100];
    char s2[100];
    
    cout << "Enter first string: ";
    cin.getline(s1, 100);
    myStrcat(s1, s2);
    cout << "Enter second string: ";
    cin.getline(s2, 100);
    myStrcat(s1, s2);

    cout << s1 << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}

//Parameters:
//  string1: first string (user input)
//  string2: second string (user input)
//Pre conditions: 
//Post conditions: The first actual parameter is altered
//Returns: Both srings combined into one; string1 + string2
void myStrcat(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    for (j=0; s2[j] != '\0'; ++j, ++i){
        s1[i] = s2[j];
    }
    s1[i] = '\0';
}


I have the below written out and it obviously only calls the function once and does not add a space. -- Why do you need to add a space if you are trying to write a function that does the same as strcat?  The strcat function doesn't add spaces unless you explicitly call it to add a space.  If you were only to use strcat, how would you "add a space" by using that function?  Whatever it is, then do the same thing using myStrcat.  You may have to call strcat (myStrcat) more than once to add space(s), plus tack on the second string.

Also, your myStrcat does not return a char *.  The strcat function does.  If you changed the return value of myStrcat to char *, then the solution becomes a simple one-liner.

If you want to "write a main driver that . . ., calls the myStrcat function to concatenate a blank space to the end of the first string, " In that call, the first argument to myStrcat should be the first string as you correctly have. What should the second argument be? Change your code accordingly. Also, you may want to make the second parameter to myStrcat a const char [] rather than a char [] as you currently have it.

I've literally been working on this for daaaaaays... -- Then you are not understanding the definition of what your function is supposed to do.  If it is to concatenate a string onto another string, wouldn't the first thing you would do is concatenate the space onto the string?  myStrcat(s1, " "); -- That logically be the first thing you would do.  Then what would be the next step?  I would post this as an answer, but my gut is to not do it because the answer is trivial, thus I don't know if it would be helpful to future readers.

Why are you calling myStrcat(s1, s2); before you assign s2?

If your doing C++, your first option should be std::string class. It supports concatenation via operators +, += and .append method.

This is probably what you want.  The assumption is that you can't modify the function signature of void myStrcat(char s1[], char s2[]); and that each substring can be 100 chars including its null char. Or rather each string typed has a max length of 99.  So the final string can be 198 printable chars, plus a space, plus a null char.
int main() {

    char s1[99+99+1+1] = { 0 };   // big enough to hold 198 characters, plus a space and a null
    char s2[99+1] = { 0 };        // big enough to hold 99 characters plus a null

    cout << "Enter first string: ";
    cin.getline(s1, 100);  // puts at most 99 chars into s1 and appends a null char

    cout << "Enter second string: ";
    cin.getline(s2, 100);  // // puts at most 99 chars into s2 and appends a null char

    char space[] = " ";
    myStrcat(s1, space);  // s1 = s1 + " "
    myStrcat(s1, s2);     // s1 = s1 + s2

    cout << s1 << endl;

    return 0;
}


You might be tempted to say, myStrcat(s1, " ") - but if that leads to a compiler error saying " " can't be cast to char []... then you'll need to change your myStrcat function sigature to be:
void myStrcat(char* dst, const char* src);

Then you could inline the space char:
myStrcat(s1, " ");  // s1 = s1 + " "
myStrcat(s1, s2);   // s1 = s1 + s2


Your first call myStrcat(s1, s2); is before you've read the second input into s2, so you're concatenating an uninitialized string, which causes undefined behavior.
You should replace that first call with
myStrcat(s1, const_cast<char *>(" "));

to concatenate the space.

I don't think " " will implicitly cast to non-const char[] with the function signature OP is using.

Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed, I've got it working now!

For safety,
void myStrcat(char s1[], size_t s1Size, char s2[])

Then check the buffer s1 does not get overrun.
void myStrcat(char s1[], size_t s1Size, const char s2[])
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    // Move 'i' to the end of s1
    while (i < s1Size - 1 && s1[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }

    // Add a space
    s1[i++] = ' ';

    // Copy characters from s2 to the end of s1 
    //  without exceeding s1Size - 1
    while (i < s1Size - 1 && s2[j] != '\0') {
        s1[i++] = s2[j++];
    }

    // Null-terminate the result
    s1[i] = '\0';
}


If the goal is to mimic strcat, note that 1) strcat does not check for buffer overruns, 2) strcat does not add spaces, and 3) strcat returns char *, which is the pointer to the destination buffer.

@PaulMcKenzie We haven't seen the assignment, so it's not clear that the return value is important; strcat() is usually just used for its side effects.

"calls the myStrcat function to concatenate a blank space to the end of the first string, then calls myStrcat again to concatenate the second string" This is not consistent with myStrcal internally adding a space on its own.
